# Where should the crud logic be implemented in mvvm?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, crud

In my MVVM Light application I do a search in a customer list. The search narrows the customer list which are displayed in a master/detail view with a datagrid (the master CustomerSearchResultView) and a separately defined usercontrol with FirstName, Lastname, Address etc, etc (the detail - CustomerSearchDetailView). Here are the main content of the master/detail view:

```
 <StackPanel MinWidth="150" >
        <TextBlock Text="Customer Search Result List" />
             <Grid>
                <DataGrid Name="CustomerList" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                      .....
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Text="Customer Details" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="30,-23,0,0"/>
                <content:CustomerSearchDetail DataContext="{Binding SelectedRow}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Both have their corresponding ViewModels. Please remark the DC for the CustomerSearchDetail, SelectedRow - it is a property on the CustomerSearchResultViewModel and is defined like this:

```
private Customer _selectedRow;
...
public Customer SelectedRow
        {
            get { return _selectedRow; }
            set
            {
                _selectedRow = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
            }
        }
...
```

**Because of this I have not defined any DC on the CustomerSearchDetailView - it is set in the Binding on the "Master" view (as shown above) and it seems to work ok.**

In my Model folder I have created the Customer class that is in use here. It implements ObservableObject and IDataErrorInfo and have public properties that raisepropertychanged events.

I run the application and everything seems to be ok. Note: the ViewModel for the CustomerSearchDetailView (that is CustomerSearchDetailViewModel.cs) is at this stage just an empty shell and not in use (as far as I can see ... the constructor is never accessed)

Now I want to add Save/Update functionality to my customer in the detail view. Ok, I add a Save button to the CustomerSearchDetailView like this:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path = SaveCommand}" Width="80" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
```

I create my "SaveCommand" RelayCommand property in my CustomerSearchDetailViewModel - but it is never accessed.

Hmmmmm ... well after some googling back and forth I come up with this:

```
 <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCustDetails}, Path = SaveCommand}" Width="80" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
```

I defined the "MyCustDetails" as a resource in this view pointing to the CustomerSearchDetailViewModel. And voila! I now hit the method when debugging ... but alas, my customer was of course "null". (In fact I spent 2 hours implementing the CommandParameter here and binding it to the "SelectedRow" Property on the master view - but the customer was still "null").

More googling and searching for mvvm examples, and I implemented my "SaveCommand" on the Customer class (the model object). And guess what? The edited customer got passed along - I could send it to my EF layer and everything seems to be ok ....

And - If you are still with me - here comes my questions:

*1.) I would like - and thought that was the "proper MVVM way" of doing things - to have my CRUD/Repository accessing in the ViewModel. How can I do that in my scenario?*

*2.) Now that I have my CRUD in place via the Model class (Customer) - should i bother with question 1? In fact I have deleted the CustomerSearchDetailViewModel and everything runs ok. I feel I have invented the View - Model (MV) framework ... :-P*

I would very much like feedback on this - and I apologize for this "wall of text".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming DC means `DataContext`

Just my opinion:

- First question is are you doing anything special with `SelectedRow` in `CustomerSearchResultViewModel`?

If the answer is no, just get rid of that property and have your `CustomSearchDetailView` bind directly to the `DataGrid` using `{Binding ElementName=CustomerList, Path=SelectedItem}`

- Now your Save / update Commands need to be used by `Button`'s in `CustomerSearchDetailView`. So instantly I'd be inclined to using a separate VM for that View and have these Command's defined there.

Now you mentioned these Commands were not accessed. Well the answer for that is because in your program you're never actually creating the `CustomerSearchDetailViewModel`.

Normal operation is your View's `DataContext` is it's VM(If it requires one. In your case you do imo cos you need it to hold your Commands)

looking at your code I'd guess your using MVVM Light. So in `ViewModelLocator` you have your `Main` property and in your Main View, you got the `DataContext` set using that `Main` property and `Source={StaticResource Locator}` where Locator is the `ViewModelLocator` created in App.xaml Resources. This thereby creates that ViewModel for that view defining that DataContext. You can ofcourse do the same in code-behind but let's not go off topic.

So in your case you got the DataContext set as `SelectedRow` which is of type `Customer` and Binding's are resolved using `DataContext` and that's why when your command's are defined in `Customer` it works fine but when it's in the VM it did not.

So why did it work when you had the commands in your VM and used

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCustDetails}, Path = SaveCommand}" Width="80" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
```

^^ That worked because the `DataContext` was not used since `Source` has been specified explicitly. and where-ever `MyCustDetails` was defined in resources, there the VM got created.

So it worked what's wrong with that?

Well it's quite a big mess. Also just like you mentioned `Customer` details in that VM was null. Well I hope you can guess why that was by now. It's because your VM was created in resources via `x:Key="MyCustDetails"` but nothing in it was ever used or set apart from when the Binding's referred to it explicitly

In this system we got commands that refer either to the Model which is plain wrong or the VM which is created as a resource just for this purpose. The `DataContext` is heavily linked to the "SearchResults" view making it not so easy for future extensions or layout updates.

If we keep the View <-> VM a 1 <-> 1 relattion we can avoid all this confusion. So in summary we can answer both your question's together. While this works, please don't let your code be like this and tweak it to better help expansion for future and comply with some basic guidelines.

**So how do we do that?**

***Approach 1:***

1. In your `CustomerSearchDetail` View, add a [DependencyProperty](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html) of type `Customer` lets call this say `SelectedCustomer`.
2. Now replace `DataContext="{Binding SelectedRow}"` with `SelectedCustomer="{Binding SelectedRow}"` in `CustomerSearchResultView`
3. Now set the DataContext of your `CustomerSerachDetailView` as it's VM similar to how `CustomerSerachResultsView` links to it's VM(guessing through DataContext Binding in xaml using the `ViewModelLocator`)
4. Now you can have your commands in `Button`'s of `CustomerSerachDetailView` just as `<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" ...`
5. Finally because `SelectedRow` is no longer the `DataContext` of the `CustomerSerachDetailsView`, your Bindings for FirstName, Lastname, Address will all appear to stop working.

We got plenty of options to address this.

First is to in each Binding use a RelativeSource FindAncestor binding pointing to `CustomerSerachDetailsView` and there via the CurrentCustomer DP(`DependencyProperty`) we created before get the appropriate field.

eg:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomerDetailsView}}, Path=CurrentCustomer.FirstName}" />
```

now if you have multiple properties this is gonna soon start getting annoying to type. So then pick a common ancestor(say 3 of these `TextBlock`s are grouped under a `StackPanel`) and apply it's DataContext as the `CurrentCustomer` element via a similar binding to ^^. Now the `StackPanel`'s children DataContext will be the Customer element so in each of their binding's you don't have to do the whole RelativeSource thing and can just mention `{Binding Path=FirstName}` and so on.

That's it. Now you got two view's with their own respective VM and a Model(`Customer`) and each have their respective tasks.

Great, we done? err not quite yet.

While *Approach 1* is better than what we started with it's still just "meh". We could do better.

***Approach 2***

MVVMLight has a `Messenger` class that will allow you to communicate between different classes in a weak dependent format. You need to look into this if you haven't already.

So what do we do with `Messenger`?

pretty simple:

1. In the setter of `SelectedRow` in `CustomerSearchResultsViewModel` we'll send a message with the new incoming `value` to `CustomerSearchDetailsViewModel`.
2. Now in `CustomerSearchResultsViewModel` we'll add a property `CurrentCustomer` and assign it this incoming value.
3. In the `CustomerSerachDetailsView` we no longer create a DP. Which means we no longer set `SelectedRow` to anything(DataContext or DP) in the `CustomerSerachDetailsView` from `CustomerSearchResultsView` ( sweet less work :) )
4. As for the way we assign `DataContext` of `CustomerSerachDetailsView` or way we bind the `Button.Command` - They remain same as *Approach 1*
5. Finally the actual "FirstName" and so Binding's. Well now `CurrentCustomer` is a property of the `CustomerSearchDetailsViewModel`. So binding to it just like how the Button bind's to it's commands

^^ this works fine now cos `DataContext` for the `TextBlock` is the VM and the property `CurrentCustomer` exists in it.

Comment: Woha! +1 for a very thorough reply. I really appreciate it! As you can understand I am just beginning to learn WPF/MVVM - coming from an ASP.NET MVC background. I will start digging into this asap, and try that messenger approach you suggested. Big thanks!